# RestTemplate return types

Tags: web-services, spring, rest

When I pass a String object type to a rest service call the String "response" contains a json representation of the rest url

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String response = restTemplate.getForObject("xxxxx", String.class, new Object[]{});
```

If I change above code to :

```
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
MyObject response = restTemplate.getForObject("xxxxx", MyObject.class, new Object[]{});
```

the type of response is now MyObject.

What is occuring here, is RestTemplate converting to Json when a string type is specified and converting to object specified when the the object return type is specified ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Basically, the `RestTemplate` makes a call to the URL specified in the first argument. The call returns a response in the form of json. It then uses the `MyObject.class` and `HttpMessageConverter` to convert the json into an object.

It uses the registered `HttpMessageConverters` to convert, so your application must be having a `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` registered in your application.

Comment: I cannot find any reference to MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter in my application, is this the default conversion type ?

Comment: yes.. `MappingJacksonHttpConverter` is added by default. Read [this](http://blog.springsource.org/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate/) blog post on springsource